# Solr hides some facet.fields when doing a distributed search

Tags: search, solr, faceted-search, facet

I am searching over 6 Solr shards (Solr version 3.5). What I recognized is that when I am doing the search in my normal standalone instance, which contains the same data I get 2 `facet_fields` in the `facet_counts` section. This is was I except:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="url">...</lst>
<lst name="url">...</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
```

As you can see there are 2 facet_fields. When I am doing the same query using multiple shards (same data), I am getting always just one facet_field:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="url">...</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
```

I am also using tagging and excluding filters in my Query. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Yonik Seeley from the solr-user mailing list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-hides-some-facet-fields-when-doing-a-distributed-search-over-multiple-shards-td3670404.html) the solution was to add some output keys to the the facets.
See also http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters